# Wrong rows and columns imported into a data frame from Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, rows

While importing data from an Excel file into a data frame via

`df = pd.read_excel('df.xlsx', skiprows = 8, usecols = 'B:AX')`,

the number of skipped rows is actually 9 (therefore columns' names from row 8 are not imported) and the data frame starts with data from column C instead of B (looks like rows and columns are somehow "indexed" from 0, making 0-8 ignored while importing). Also, a column which contains "+" in its name ("Name **+** Code") is imported into `pandas` with a minus sign instead ("Name **-** Code"). What could be causing this kind of behavior (if there's only one cause for these)?

The computer I'm working on has Python (3.8.6) freshly installed, together with `pandas` and `openpyxl` (via `pip install`). The same code on my other computer works perfectly fine (8 rows are skipped, data from columns B:AX is imported correctly, "+" stays "+" in all `df.columns`).